# How do you send info from 2 different collections to one route in iron-router for meteor?

Tags: meteor, collections, iron-router

How do you send info from 2 different collections to one route in iron-router for meteor?

For example I have a `Posts` and `Comments` collection and wanted to assign both `Posts.findOne(this.params._id)` and `Comments.find({postId: this.params._id})` to the `data` field of route `detailedPost` route so that I could display both the post details and the comments for that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily assign them to parameters of the `data` object:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('detailedPost', {
    path: '/post/:id',
    data: function() {
      return {
        post: Posts.findOne(this.params._id),
        comments: Comments.find({postId: this.params._id}),
      };
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks and a note for others with the same problem you access them in your templates using {{#with post}} {{/with}} or {{#each comments}} {{/each}}

Comment: Or just `{{post.title}}`, `{{post.body}}`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Hubert. I didn't know that and it helps a lot. All the documentation I find on Meteor has examples of the router side but not how to access the template side of things so this is needed somewhere.